# tmux zoom (z) not working for me

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux 1.6 with a `Ctrl-a` prefix, but `Ctrl-a z` does not zoom for me. The prefix does work otherwise. So, for example, Ctrl- moves to the pane on the right, etc.

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: what is the tmux command prompt?

Comment: Press CTRL-A, then ":". That is the prompt. Prefix-z is normally bound to the command `resize-pane -Z`. Try running that manually. Then try Prefix-? to see, if your keybinding for Prefix-z is defined and correct.

Comment: "resize-pane -z" does nothing. "Prefix-z" returns "Unknown command: Prefix-z"

Comment: `resize-pane -Z`, capital Z. And "Prefix-" was my Shorthand for "CTRL-A - ". Check out the manual page for "resize-pane"

Comment: z is unbound according to the "?" command. I have version 1.6 do I need to get a later version?

Comment: You probably need at least version 1.8 (March 2013) to have the zoom implemented by `resize-pane -Z`, according to the changelog for tmux.

Comment: As stated here, it's introduced in 1.8 version: http://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the hidden comments, zoom feature was introduced in version 1.8. So you need to upgrade in order to use zoom.